# ArcGIS Field Calculator strip words after spaces

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

I have a feature class which contains 40,000 mailing addresses.  Each address contains the street address, city, state and zipcode separated by spaces.

Example 1:  123 Northwest Johnson St Cleveland Ohio 12345
Example 2:  PO Box 3 Pine Springs Ohio 12345

I want to pull out just the street addresses.  How do I say: trim off the string starting at the 3rd or 4th to last space?

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.  I'm trying combinations of split, trim, etc. but can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in pure Python, I am not sure about differences when using ArcGIS:

```
ad1 = "123 Northwest Johnson St Cleveland Ohio 12345"
ad2 = "PO Box 3 Pine Springs Ohio 12345"
ad1split = ad1.split(" ")
ad2split = ad2.split(" ")
print ' '.join( ad1split[: len(ad1split)-3 ] ) # 123 Northwest Johnson
print ' '.join( ad2split[: len(ad1split)-3 ] ) # PO Box 3
```

This however only works if all addresses have the same format.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the formats of the addresses are not the same which is why I just want to cut off the last three parts of each address.

Comment: I edited my answer, it now removes the last three words from every line